# Alternativa a pixelsearch

Tags: python, python-3.x

hay una funcion en autoit llamada `PixelSearch()`, estuve buscando una parecida en python pero lo único que encuentro es el `GetPixel()`, quisiera saber como podría recrearla en python

Answer (score 1):

Kiyosaki, la idea es que presentes el código que llevas avanzado. De todos modos te dejo un ejemplo:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("una_imagen.jpg")
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
pixel_rgb = rgb_im.getpixel((1, 1))
print(pixel_rgb)
```

Como bien dijiste, getpixel (de PIL.Image) obtiene un pixel, y devuelve una tupla de largo tres, con los valores RGB. Espero haber sido de ayuda.